# Why can't I access the files that I own?

Tags: permissions

I encountered a very strange situation with a bunch of directories:

```
user1$ ls -l example/
ls: cannot access 'example/a.txt': Permission denied
ls: cannot access 'example/b.txt': Permission denied
total 0
-????????? ? ? ? ?            ?  a.txt
-????????? ? ? ? ?            ?  b.txt

user1$ sudo ls -l example/
total 12345
drw-rwxr-x 2 user1 user1    4096 Jul  7  2018  ./
drwxrwxr-x 7 user1 user1   54321 Dec 14 12:15  ../
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user1 user1 2444333 Mar 17  2018  a.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user1 user1 1333222 Mar 17  2018  b.txt
```

With `sudo`, I can read the files successfully, change the permissions, etc. Without it, there is no way I can access those files. I tried to `sudo chown user1:user1` the files, as well as `sudo chmod a+r` them: the commands succeed, but nothing changes.

What could possibly have happened to those files? How do I make it possible to access them?

Comment: `ls -ld example`

Comment: `drw-` - no execute permission for the directory for your `user1`.